# Узнать степень узла у дерева с++

Tags: c++

Собственно сабж, степень узла - это количество его поддеревьев 0 или 1 или 2 и т.д., но у меня дерево бинарного поиска, соответственно их не может быть более 2!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct tree {
    int data;
    tree *left,*right;
};
tree *root;

void add(int x, tree *&root)
{
    if (!root)
    {
        root = new tree;
        root->data = x;
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (x < root->data)
        add(x, root->left);
    else if (x > root->data)
        add(x, root->right);
}

void stepen(int x, tree *root)
{
    if (x->left != NULL && x->right = NULL)
        cout << "stepen 1\n";
    if (x->left == NULL && x->right != NULL)
        cout << "stepen 1\n";
    if (x->left != NULL && x->right != NULL)
        cout << "stepen 2\n" ;
}

void deletet(tree *&root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        delete(root->left);
        delete(root->right);
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
    }
}

void print(tree *root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) cout << root->data << ' ';
        else 
        { 
            print(root->left); print(root->right); 
        }
    }
}
int main() {

    ifstream in("input.txt");

    int x;
    while (in.peek() != EOF) {
        in >> x;
        add(x, root);
    }
    print(root); cout << endl;
    stepen(6, root); cout << endl;
    deletet(root);
    in.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эммм... хранить эту степень и при заполнении ее устанавливать?

Comment: непонимаю, можно поподробнее?

Comment: ну, в tree добавить поле числовое и заполнять его

Comment: незнаю как смогу это реализовать, да и с этой реализацией проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то это просто `int(node->left != 0) + int(node->right != 0)` - т.е. количество дочерних узлов...

У вас вроде идея верна, но что вы пытаетесь сделать?

```
void stepen(int x, tree *root)
```

`x` - это же просто число, какое же может быть `x->left`?! Узел у вас - это `tree*`. Надо найти интересующий вас узел, и смотреть указатели у него...

Comment: я просто незнаю как правильно задать

Answer (score 0):

Копипастим бинпоиск из `add`. Если не нашлось, вернуть -1, например. Если нашлось, то

```
return !!root->left + !!root->right;
```